# Zxing Not decoding the 2D Data Matrix code having large amount of Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image-processing, zxing

My project needs a library which is able to read large amount of data 
from 2D data Matrix .Now I am using Zxing which is 
decoding only 2D data Matrix with less amount of data and not able to read 
large amount of data in 2D Data Matrix.But its working fine with QR 
codes with any amount of data
this is my 2D data Matrix data

Any other library is available for 2D data matrix scanning 
I have downloaded libdmtx library but I don't know how can i use it with my project because it is a C file?

Please give me solutions for this

Thanks in Advance

this is my 2D data Matrix data

[image]

zxing 1.7 Not Working with these above code
I need  other libraries to decode 2D data matrix of above type

I found libmtx library for 2D data matrix decoding 
But how can i integrate libmtx with xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library scans this code fine -- but perhaps not in the C# code. The C# code is old and unsupported. You may have to re-port it from Java.

Comment: sorry zxing1.7 Not working with 2D data matrix of large amount of data

Comment: I think that's what I said? You have to re-port even the latest code. C# is not supported.

Comment: I am using in Xcode Zxing 1.7 its able to decode small data contains 2d data matrix

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this [library](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/csharp/datamatrix/).

Use also http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: I am using Zxing But not working. library is C# how can i use it here

Comment: @Ramkumar TR, are see this link also http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list  ?

Comment: Above given link contains numbers of library and those are properly working.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am using zxing 1.7 itself..but not working for 2D matrix contains large data..

Comment: sorry 1.6 I am using...1.7 is available now.is it work for 2D data matrix

Answer (score 0):

Anyone interested; There's now a [cocoa pod for ZXing support](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC).

In most cases people will be fine [using the native libs in iOS7](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/), but this does not work for datamatrix (and some other formats.